# Taxpayer program won't to run all the way though

Tags: c#, compareto

Every time I run the program it goes through the first four Taxpayers with no problem, but when it should ask me for the fifth taxpayers information it stops. I have been looking all morning for a solution. What am I doing wrong, or missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestApp
{
class Rates
{
    public readonly int incomeLimit;
    public readonly double lowTax;
    public readonly double highTax;

    public Rates()
    {
        incomeLimit = 30000;
        lowTax = .15;
        highTax = .28;
    }
    public Rates(int limit, double lowRate, double highRate)
    {
        limit = incomeLimit;
        lowRate = lowTax;
        highRate = highTax;
    }
    public double CalcTax(double income)
    {

        double tax;
        if (income < incomeLimit)
        tax = income * lowTax;
        else
            tax = income * highTax;
        return tax;
    }
}
class Taxpayer : IComparable
{
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public double grossIncome { get; set; }
    public double taxOwed
    {
        get
        {
            return taxOwed;
        }
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(Object o)
    {
        int returnVal;
        Taxpayer temp = (Taxpayer)o;
        if (this.taxOwed > temp.taxOwed)
            returnVal = 1;
        else if (this.taxOwed < temp.taxOwed)
            returnVal = -1;
        else returnVal = 0;

        return returnVal;

    }
    public static void getRates()
    {
        Taxpayer tax = new Taxpayer();


        int limit = 0;
        double lowRate = 0;
        double highRate = 0;
        char input;
    Console.Write("Do you want default values (enter D) or enter your own (enter O)?");
        input = Char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()));

        switch (input)
        {
            case 'D':
                Rates def = new Rates();
                limit = def.incomeLimit;
                lowRate = def.lowTax;
                highRate = def.highTax;
                def.CalcTax(tax.grossIncome);
                break;
            case 'O':
                Rates own = new Rates(limit, lowRate, highRate);
                Console.Write("Enter the dollar limit ");
                limit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the low rate ");
                lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the high rate ");
                highRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                own.CalcTax(tax.grossIncome);
                break;
        }

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Rates taxRates =  new Rates();
        Taxpayer[] taxarray = new Taxpayer[5];


        for (int x = 1; x < taxarray.Length; ++x)
        {
            taxarray[x] = new Taxpayer();
            Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}: ", x);
            taxarray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter gross income for taxpayer {0}: ", x);
            taxarray[x].grossIncome = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Taxpayer.getRates();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < taxarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1} income {2:c} Tax is {3:c}", taxarray[i].SSN, taxarray[i].grossIncome, taxRates.CalcTax(taxarray[i].grossIncome));
        }
        Array.Sort(taxarray);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < taxarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1} income {2:c} Tax is {3:c}", taxarray[i].SSN, taxarray[i].grossIncome, taxRates.CalcTax(taxarray[i].grossIncome));
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `for (int x = 1; x < taxarray.Length; ++x)` why are you starting with 1?

Comment: And further down the OP starts another with 0.  Not very consistent..

Answer (score 2):

```
    Taxpayer[] taxarray = new Taxpayer[5];
    for (int x = 1; x < taxarray.Length; ++x)
```

Arrays are zero-based in C#. Starting at 1 and < 5 is {1,2,3,4} = 4 tax payers.

You should start at zero:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < taxarray.Length; x++)
```

Also: don't bother with `++x` vs `x++`, unless you care about the **result** of the operation (which you don't in this example). Let the JIT worry about such micro-optimisations.

Comment: Thank you I can now get through all the user inputs. Now I am having trouble getting the users inputs to be included into the calculations. Even after the user inputs the information the default values are always used.

Answer (score 0):

This line start at index 1

```
 for (int x = 1; x < taxarray.Length; ++x)
```

Arrays starts at index 0
So your input code should be changed to

```
   for (int x = 0; x < taxarray.Length; x++)
   {
        taxarray[x] = new Taxpayer();
        Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
        taxarray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter gross income for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
        taxarray[x].grossIncome = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Taxpayer.getRates();
   }
```

Start with index 0 and ask the input for x+1 to not confound the user

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it is never asking you for the zeroth taxpayer.  C# arrays are 0 based, and you are starting at 1.